Comparing a model regression of $Y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$ and a model of $Y$ on $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ for correlated $X_1$, $X_2$?
Suppose I have two linear regression models:

$Y = \beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2$
$Y = \alpha_0+\alpha_1(X_1+X_2)+\alpha_2(X_1-X_2)$

for correlated $X_1$, $X_2$.
It is easy to see that the coefficients from model 1 and 2 are different.  I am trying to address three questions:

How does the correlation of $X_1$ and $X_2$ impact whether the least squares estimates of $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are equivalent to $\hat{\alpha_0}$ and $\hat{\alpha_1}$, respectively? What if they were independent?

Would the fitted $\widehat{Y}$ be different, and with new data?

If I did regularization, would that affect the coefficients?


Thanks for any thoughts above.

The expression 2 is not an identifiable model, so it is rarely considered as a "model".

Is this a homework question? In that case could you explain what you do not understand. Also read this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

@Zhanxiong with unidentifiable, you mean the case when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are fully positive or negative correlated? But in that case then expression 1 is neither identifiable.

@SextusEmpiricus I mean different parameters $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \neq (\alpha_1 + \delta, \alpha_2 - \delta)$ give the identical model.

@Zhanxiong you must be misreading that line since the second model is equivalent to $$Y = \alpha_0 + (\alpha_1+\alpha_2) X_1 + (\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) X_2$$ then for example (4,4) will give $$Y = \alpha_0 + 8 X_1 + 0 X_2$$ and (3,5) will give $$Y = \alpha_0 + 8 X_1 - 2 X_2$$ which is not identical.


As you have noted, the coefficients are different, and the least squares estimates won't be equal across the two models.  Correlation has nothing to do with it.  A small amount of algebra should convince you that $\beta_1 = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $\beta_2 = \alpha_1 - \alpha_2$.

The fitted $Y$ values will be the same, as the variables in the second equation are a linear transform of the variables in the first equation.

Yes; if regularization didn't affect the coefficients, it'd be pointless.


An example:
z <- rnorm(100)
x1 <- rnorm(100) + z
x2 <- rnorm(100) + z
y <- 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(100)

d1 <- x1 + x2
d2 <- x1 - x2

Cutting out a lot of extraneous text, we get:
> summary(lm(y~x1+x2))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.96300    0.09440   10.20   <2e-16 ***
x1           2.05019    0.08047   25.48   <2e-16 ***
x2           2.97066    0.08301   35.79   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9421 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9766,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9761 
F-statistic:  2024 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm(y~d1+d2))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.96300    0.09440  10.201  < 2e-16 ***
d1           2.51043    0.03954  63.495  < 2e-16 ***
d2          -0.46023    0.07155  -6.432 4.76e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9421 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9766,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9761 
F-statistic:  2024 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

As you can see, the summary statistics are identical, and the coefficient estimates are not.
